# merge several .csv files into one array

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

I'm trying to load several .csv files (with the same columns) into the same array from different directories.

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv "PATH1"
$csv1 = Import-Csv "PATH2"
$csv1 | Export-Csv C:\test.csv
```

This just outputs the last .csv loaded, what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Hey this should to the trick if i can stop importing the headers of the 2nd .csv file?

Comment: found out i could use the += on the 2nd csv file to add it to the array. thanks

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - `Get-Content ...| Set-Content ...` might "work", except that if it's a CSV in standard format (first line is headers) he'll end up with a record in the middle that duplicates his headers, e.g., Name="Name" Address="Address" etc. His solution using `+=` is better.

Comment: hey @JeffZeitlin if i wanted to add an additional colum per line stating what path the file came from how would i do this?

Comment: @Bunion - That actually gets complicated. You'd actually end up creating a new PSObject with the same "shape" as the records in the CSV, adding a new member to that new object, copying the fields from the CSV record into the custom object, setting the new member, and then either adding the new object to a new array, or exporting it to the CSV (with the -append) switch.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin No need to make a new object when you could use `-PassThru` on `Add-Member` or `Select-Object` to make a calculated property. @Bunion Here is a one liner that adds that property: `($(Import-Csv "PATH1" | Add-Member -Name "SourcePath" -Value "PATH1" -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru) + $(Import-Csv "PATH2" | Add-Member -Name "SourcePath" -Value "PATH2" -MemberType NoteProperty -PassThru)) | Export-CSV C:\test.csv`

Comment: @BenH - I recall trying something like that, and had some issues because of an array being involved. I'll look into that again if I get the chance; it would certainly be more elegant to do it your way...

Comment: Please do not edit an answer into a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv). The `Import-Csv` cmdlet accepts an array of path strings as input, so all you need to do (assuming that all your CSVs have the same fields) is something like this:

```
$src = 'C:\path\to\input1.csv', 'C:\path\to\input2.csv', ...
$dst = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

Import-Csv $src | Export-Csv $dst -NoType
```

If you want an additional column with the path of the source file you need some additional steps, though:

```
$src | ForEach-Object {
  $path = $_
  Import-Csv $path | Select-Object *,@{n='Path';e={$path}}
} | Export-Csv $dst -NoType
```